# How to declare /var/www as Tomcat and Railo ROOT?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, coldfusion, root, railo

I wanted to have Apache's `/var/www` to be the root for my railo CMS? I put the railo.war into `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps` and put the following into my `/etc/tomcat6/server.xml`:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
<Context path="" docBase="/var/www"/>
```

Now when I put an index.cfm into /var/www and go to `http://localhost` I get the following error

```
Railo [3.2.2.000] - Error (java.io.IOException)
Message No such file or directory
Cause   java.io.IOException
Java Stacktrace 
No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method):-2
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883):883
at railo.commons.io.res.type.file.FileResource.getOutputStream(FileResource.java:220):220
at railo.commons.io.res.type.file.FileResource.getOutputStream(FileResource.java:209):209
at railo.commons.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:135):135
```

So obviously Railo doesn't accept that `.cfm`s are outside the webapps folder?

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: perhaps a permission problem?

Comment: oh gosh, thanks for the hint! thought it was a tomcat6 conf issue!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have properly set your Tomcat Host's Context for root context and a document base (Web root) of `/var/www` with this:

```
<Context path="" docBase="/var/www" />
```

However, this is telling Tomcat that a Web application lives under `/var/www` but you have not deployed a WAR's contents to that location. You placed your railo.war under `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`, which tells me that you've probably used the standard Ubuntu repository install of the `tomcat6` package. If this assumption is correct, then you should be able to browse to your Railo WAR at `http://localhost:8080/railo/` by default.

What you want to do is extract your railo.war file and place its contents beneath `/var/www` (namely, the `WEB-INF` folder from the WAR). Below are some commands that would allow you to properly deploy a Railo WAR under `/var/www/` using the `<Host>` configuration you have specified in your question. I'll assume you're on Ubuntu, with the `tomcat6` package installed, and have a Railo WAR file in your home directory as `~/railo.war`. The Ubuntu `tomcat6` package has Tomcat running as the `tomcat6` user, so you'll probably want to give file/directory ownership to that user, otherwise Railo would not be able to write any files to disk.

```
# Change directory to destination for Railo WAR contents:
cd /var/www

# Extract Railo WAR contents:
sudo jar xvf ~/railo.war

# Give Tomcat user file ownership:
sudo chown -R tomcat6 /var/www/

# Restart Tomcat service to ensure root app is picked up:
sudo service tomcat6 restart
```

You should now be able to browse to the `index.cfm` file included with the Railo WAR at `http://localhost:8080/`, which is now located at `/var/www/index.cfm`.

Keep in mind that there is nothing discussed here concerning connecting your Apache HTTPD Web server to Railo/Tomcat. You might want to read [here](http://jamiekrug.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/8/31/cfml-tomcat-apache-ajp-proxy-redux) or [here](http://corfield.org/blog/post.cfm/Railo_for_Dummies_Part_IV_Appendix) for Apache-to-Tomcat proxy options. The Railo Wiki also has this [Installation Guides](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/Railo_Installation) section.