# tomcat 7 instance not starting on ubuntu

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04, instanceof

I'm new to Tomcat, Apache and Ubuntu and i have no idea where to look for logs.

I've followed the article letter by letter of how to create multiple instances of tomcat but ive git a glitch and im not sure how to go about debugging it. Three quarters down the page im supposed to be kick starting the instance but all i get back is [fail], no error message. Im not sure where to look or what i can do to deug this.

https://github.com/getrailo/railo/wiki/Ubuntu-12.04-Railo-4-Beta-with-Tomcat7-multi-instance

Any help appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to get where i want and thats to have multiple instances of tomcat all running at the same time. I wouldn't have been able to do this without the article mentioned in these posts, so big thanks to all their hard work.

The reason i was getting [fail] message when trying to start up tomcat, was because i followed the java options steps based on my hardware, that cost me a day!! When reset to its default i was able to start/stop my instances with no errors. I would advise you to use the default (JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC") then tweak when you have everything running.

If you get to the point where you are getting permission or folder not found error when trying to browse your instance, it is because tomcat7 doesn't have [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185933/how-to-declare-var-www-as-tomcat-and-railo-root) to your working folder (follow [this](http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/railo-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk) to know how to create your working folder with railo deployment).

Hope this saves someone hours/days.